# Transferring local svn to remote forge

Tags: svn

Okay, so I developed this program and used SVN for revisions, on a local repository.

Is it even possible to transfer this information to a forge, which is also svn based?

I've been told I need to use git-svn, in which case I would love to have some guidance on how to use it, under Windows, preferrably.

Thanks in advance,
--Gabriel

Answer (score 2):

For transferring your repository once, or to do it in one direction only, you're looking for `svnsync`, which should come as part of your Subversion install.

EDIT:

- This works for an empty target repository, or a target repository that has previously been `svnsync`'d.
- To get the command-line versions for Windows I recommend the [Slik SVN builds](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download). They include `svnsync`.
- This link can be useful: [Importing an existing SVN repository into Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/SubversionFAQ#How_do_I_import_an_existing_Subversion_repository?).

Comment: Is that also valid if my forge is currently completely empty?

Comment: Also, do you know if it's possible to do that with tortoise-svn?

Comment: Okay, now I found myself another problem: turns out I already uploaded the head revision on my comp. by deleting .svn files and checking out, so I can't svnsync now, I get an error about "'sync-lock':
could not remove a property".



Would removing every file and then retrying work?

Comment: I seem to have a problem iwth "pre-revprop-change" on svnsync init. My god this is tougher than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

If your new svn host supports `svnadmin load` that is the most straight forward and compatible way to move a repository.

1. Export your current repository to a file with [`svnadmin dump`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re31.html).
2. Copy the file to your new host.
3. Load the file into an empty repository with [`svnadmin load`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re36.html).

Comment: I don't think I can execute this command on my new host as it is a public forge

Comment: @kelmer, sites like sourceforge.net gives you shell access to enable this: https://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/SVN%20adminrepo other sites may wrap "svnadmin load" in a web interface where you upload your svndump-file.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not the case. http://forxa.mancomun.org does not allow that, as far as I know.